# What is the meaning of "play it razor" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Context: Sheriff & Doctor Samuel discuss about Michael Myers (serial killer) escapes & wandering into the streets to get his sister *Laurie* who is adopted by Strodes.

> Doctor: I don't know, Sheriff, but it's not good.
>
> Sheriff: If I break a promise I made a long time ago, then you must
>   promise that **you will play it razor, and I mean razor**, straight with
>   me.
>
> Sheriff: (Dailing phone to Strodes)

Comment: Please wait at least a day or so before accepting an answer. It appears that you've been accepting wrong or misleading answers very quickly the last few days. Give people time to comment, upvote, and downvote. That process will uncover errors and omissions in the earliest answers. This is how StackOverflow works most successfully. More info [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Comment: @Max That is why i am including **context** also in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Straight* can mean *honest* or *direct*. *Razor straight* means *straight as a razor*. It is figurative language that means **really** straight. *Play it straight* means *be straight*.

Together, *play it razor straight with me* then means *be really honest/direct with me*. The sheriff wants the doctor to be honest with him; he wants to be told the whole truth.